# Aggregate failure codes in bash

Tags: bash

I've got a script which has multiple stages, and at each stage it's possible to fail, but the script can carry on running.

Concretely, I generate some json, and check if the diff is correct. The diff could be wrong, but it doesn't stop the next stage of json being produced.

How can I aggregate the failure codes of diff, so that I return 1 if any diff returned > 1, and zero otherwise, without just ending as soon as a failure occured?

Basically, it's just folding `||` over the result codes, but I can't seem to find a nice way to `||` a string with a return code.

Skeleton:

```
main_result=0
for s in stage1 stage2 stage3; do
    diff <(generate-stuff) expected-$stage
    result=$?
    # something like main_result=$main_result || $result
done

exit $main_result
```

Comment: Do you really mean `diff returned > 1` or equal to 1?

Comment: @anubhava I really mean `> 1`. From the man page `Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.`

Comment: You make it a lot more complicated than it should be.  Just set `main_result` to 1 if one of the generated files is not what you expect: `diff <(generate-stuff) expected-$stage || main_result=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Logical or* can be done as:

```
main_result=$((main_result || result))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `$(())` which is explained [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html):

```
#!/bin/sh
main_result=0
main_result=$((main_result || 0))
echo $main_result
main_result=$((main_result || 1))
main_result=$((main_result || 0))
echo $main_result
```

Results in:

```
0
1
```

So all you need to do is

```
main_result=$((main_result || $?))
```